# solr.MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory fails for float value comparion

Tags: solr

To get Min Value i used "MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory" Processor. It Works fine with integer values. But for float values fails.

I have below values

```
Price1: 99.95,
Price2: 119.95,
```

I have copied those value in multi valued field as follows

```
<processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">Price1</str>
    <str name="source">Price2</str>
    <str name="dest">min_prices</str>
</processor>
```

And then applied "MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory" processor,

```
<processor class="solr.MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">min_prices</str>
</processor>
```

In result it returns min_prices is 119.95 which is wrong,

```
min_prices:[119.5]
```

How can i applied MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory for float values?

Comment: What is the field types of the fields you're working with? (i.e. for `min_prices`)

Comment: it's pfloat type

Comment: I tried with piece of java code which is used in the class...and passed it the float values...it works perfectly...I passes the values...12.23, 32.83,72.123, 112.253,152.243 and the answer I got as 12.23

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Can You Please share your code.

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Collection values = new ArrayList<>();
  values.add(12.23);
  values.add(32.83);
  values.add(72.123);
  values.add(112.253);
  values.add(152.243);
  Collection result = values;
  result = Collections.singletonList((Object) Collections.min(values));
  System.out.println("min ele : :" + result);

 }
}

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti How to do its integration with Solr

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Can You Please paste it's integration in answer

Comment: there is not need to intergrate it...its the code in the same class which you are using...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti for this we not used any class. We just applied MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory

Comment: you try using pfloats for your field

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti That we are already using.

Comment: check if your field holds the multiple values...you can check that by removing the MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory ...check if the field is able to hold multiple values

Comment: did you find anything on it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222644/discussion-between-deepali-jadhav-and-abhijit-bashetti).

Comment: Are you getting the multiple values in your field before finding the min value?